# Using tor with SET to bypass firewall policy?

Tags: smtp, tor, kali-linux

I'm doing a credential harvesting attack using SET from backtrack. I want to sent a spoof email using an open relay server. However, any outbound connection for smtp is blocked by the firewall.

I want to know is it possible that using tor i can tunnel my traffic and go un-detected? If not possible with tor what others ways i can use to tunnel the traffic.

Comment: You want to go undetected by whom: The target or your local firewall? If it is your firewall that is the concern, we need to know more about the situation.

Comment: I need somehow to bypass the fw restriction for outbound 25 and connect using something as tor. I want to make direct connection with open relay server on the internet.

Comment: @user970533 - You should go through the proper channels to do this.  Trying to bypass firewall restrictions is a great way to be fired.

Comment: fired? I'm paid to do this:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you state that you cannot email at all. What you need is another piece to the puzzle: a forwarder. You need to tunnel your SMTP traffic through your local FW to a forwarder that will relay it to port 25 to the target.

All this is assuming that the target is receiving SMTP (port 25) and is not also using webmail ....

Comment: I can email but not using telnet as i can do sitting from home computer. Would tor not act as a tunnel.?

Comment: When you say 'email' do you mean SMTP or do you mean 'webmail'?

Comment: As i explained above i can email using web only.

Comment: Then my post applies as-is. A tunnel is the least of your worries. You need an asset on the other side of your firewall to forward port 80 to port 25.

Comment: would opening a redirecter on my home pc and connect it using ssh tunnel from office pc would do the trick?

Comment: Now we are closer to something that will work. You have to worry about your office firewall, but you have the right idea.

Comment: thank you schroeder. You always help me with my threads. I appreciate this very much. I'm going to work on this now.

Comment: @everyone. This is to update as to what i have been able to do in the day. I sat up an ssh server on bt vm at my home network running on port 443 just to add obscurity. I was able to connect to the remote ssh server from my organization network PC running bk (vm) using TOR. To achieve this i made a simple NAT rule at the router of my home network. Right now its ssh/https over TOR tunnel. I still have not made the remote port forwarding rule on ssh server to have it relay on remote open relay server.

Comment: I'm just stuck in how will i tell my local organization network to use TOR as proxy so when I use SET and it ask my for open-relay server the traffic should go using the established TOR tunnel through ssh ultimately redirected to smtp server of my choice. Since i want to attack / clone the website on local network I don't want all the traffic to go out of tunnel is there a way i can tell ssh which traffic to forward.

Comment: I think you need to look at 'ssh tunneling' and 'proxychains' http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=1496

Comment: I read the link that you sent me. It was very informational. But I'm confused on two things. If i'm using tor to tunnel then i don't need ssh because while using proxychains i can tell whatever console application to use tor in my case which is to telnet smtp server. I don't need ssh then? But there is a command on the tutorial which says  "ssh -D 9000 me@whatever.com". Using this command i would be tunneling both from tor and ssh right? Please clarify

Comment: You are correct - you would be tunneling ssh through the TOR tunnel. Consider not using TOR, or use both.

Comment: it worked:) but i got a few other problems. Would write a new thread

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you can send email with TOR depends on the exit policy of whatever exit node you end up using.  Almost invariably outgoing TCP 25 is blocked by tor exit nodes because of spammers.

More importantly,  most email providers are using the [Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) which can be used to detect forged email.  Welcome to 2012 where most stupid hacks are prevented by simple security systems.

There is nothing magical about sending spoofed email,  and you can do it with telnet or netcat,  you just need to be able to access your victim's SMTP server on port 25 and deliver the forged email directly.  You should be able to find a socks proxy server that can do this.

Comment: thanks for the update. I guess you read too much into the text. I got 0 problem in sending fake / spoof email to abc organization. I can do this as long as there is no filtering device e.g firewall between me and internet. Sender policy framework or anything similar has not been configured on the target mail server. I cannot do it with telnet as it makes an connection through the fw which is blocked? thus is my reason to write this post. What particularly i asked if i can use SET with tor? Thanks for the sender policy framework. Nice reading. Talking about magic you got no idea what SET can do

Comment: @user970533 Yes, I have answered your question.

Comment: If you can email, then you can telnet to the email port .... Your question goes in several directions at once, so do not be surprised if responses are not what you expected.

Comment: No that not true. I can email using web interface not port 25. It just times out the connection when i try with telnet. It doesn't even makes a connection thus the firewall. I cannot talk to open relay server while sitting behind the firewall. Sorry for being rude.

Comment: @user970533 email is sent using port 25, using SMTP.   Use an open socks proxy (other than tor) to bypass your firewall.  These proxies are plentiful,  tens of thousands exist,  you just have to find them.  You have just been spoon fed,  shitty script kiddie hacks.

Comment: @user970533 Then, you cannot email; you can surf. That's an important piece of information. You need to tunnel through port 80 to a relay outside that will forward to the email port.

Comment: @Rook by calling it shitty script kiddie hacks you are negating a fundamental principle known to all hacker which is to always go for the weakest link first; the low hanging fruit. In my case its the poor configured mail-server. What can you do if you can spoof google top level executive email id? Would you discard it say its script kiddie or you would use it full potential. Hackers are opportunist not deterministic or what you strictly anal (sorry for the word).

Comment: @schroeder that exactly what policies rules. I even tried scanning my host computer over internet through the use of online port scanning tools its all filtered. I want to tunnel as i said. Would socks as rook said would do the trick or i can do that with TOR instead? What your prefer.

Comment: Rook used his words because you are not hacking or being opportunistic; you are running scripts without understanding.

Comment: @user970533 Scanning from the outside will not help you. You will only learn the inbound firewall rules. You want to know the outbound rules. TOR will not help you - you need something to swap the ports.

Comment: @schroeder I'm stating a limitation which is not inherent with the tool its the environment. Did i blamed SET? Like ever This thread is not about the tool its about me stuck in use case which needs some creative answers.

Comment: @user970533 - It sounds like you need to work on the problem some more.  It also sounds like the answer would be localized to only your problem.

Comment: @ Ramhound I 'm just here to learn and share. Schroeder has helped learn new things a slot.